# Travel planning web sites

Tags: online-resources, planning

I am currently planning a 2 month trip through China, and I wanted to know what are the best online options to plan a trip.

First off : I am really looking for an alternative to a spreadsheet. Something very versatile where I can keep my ideas organized more than a web site like tripit.

What I am expecting from such a website is:

- Adding locations (cities) and a optional a date at which I am expecting to be there.
- Adding place to see, attractions, things to do at each of theses locations.

Nice to have features would be:

- Giving me options of the transportation methods between my location
- Giving me options of place to stay at theses places.

What are my options?

Comment: Transportation methods between places is hard to find, especially outside of Europe/USA.  China is really hard, as is Central Asia.  It's often easier on the ground, however, Lonely Planet forums is often the next best bet.  Or here, of course ;)

Comment: That is why I list it as a nice to have. I am really looking for an alternative to a spreadsheet.

Comment: Would this question be more suited to http://webapps.stackexchange.com ?

Comment: how about something like evernote.com? (here is one example http://blog.evernote.com/2011/07/07/travel-series-planning-a-trip-with-evernote/)

Answer (score 8):

You could try [TripIt](http://www.tripit.com).

TripIt allows you to create your own travel-agent like itinerary by forwarding booking confirmations to an email address or entering things manually.

Answer (score 4):

I plan my trip with a custom map in My Places by [Google Maps](https://maps.google.com/). You can save your personal point of interest (your booked hotels, restaurants & attractions) and access it from every device.

To find place to stay, I would recommend [Airbnb](https://www.airbnb.com/), [TripAdvisor](http://www.tripadvisor.com/) or [Room77](https://www.room77.com/).

For transportation, There is [Waytogo](http://www.cleartrip.com/waytogo) or [Kayak](http://www.kayak.com/)

Comment: Excellent. I just love having a map and the ability to share the whole thing.